# When does iOS 7 close my app?

Tags: ios, ios7

I have an app that runs in the background. This application is called to be able to update and then goes to sleep.

For some reason, it stops working after a few hours.

I have some theories but I can not find documentation about them.

1. iOS closes applications when there's a lack of memory.

   - Does anyone know  the order used in this process?
   - Does it choose applications that have been running longer, which occupy more memory, or does it simply randomly close apps to get the needed memory?
2. Is there a maximum time limit that an application may be running in background?
3. Is there a maximum number of repeats for an `NSTimer`?
4. Does iOS close applications in the background if battery levels are reduced in order to conserve power?

If anyone can answer these questions, or provide some information about them, that would be great.

The theories are founded on the basis of report of clients.

Comment: What type of background mode is your app registered for?

Comment: This app work with a NSTimer in Main Thread. I know I should not be so used. but it was not I who made the app, and do not have power to decide matches it (I'm not the project manager), without presenting strong reasons.

Comment: Have you tried using local notifications instead of an NSTimer? Those work properly in the background and when the app is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer point by point (in a simplicistic way):

1. An app running in background which is going into out of memory condition should get killed by the operating system, but its application delegate should receive an `applicationWillTerminate` message.
2. No time limit is officially stated for background running apps.
3. `NSTimer` can only be of one kind out of two: repeating or non-repeating. You can refer to the [NSTimer class reference documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) for the evidence of such aspect.
4. The app can't do that, by Apple policy if I can remember correctly. If the device is running low on battery, it must not intervene on open apps to extend battery duration.

For a complete description of apps background running modes you should refer to Apple Developer Documentation [at this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3).

It is a good starting point to understand multitasking and the correct policy to adopt if your app has to responsibly run in the background.

Comment: thanks for the reply. the first point I wanted to know what happens to my app if the user opens the app and then open another 50 without killing any. the operating system will be forced to close some right?

Comment: At this point I have to go by interpretation: if the 50 apps don't bring the system in out-of-memory condition it's fine; if one among them is eating up all of the remaining memory (i.e. is undiscriminately claiming all of the remaining memory), then that is the one that gets killed. Please consider also the fact that iOS has a virtual memory system, the link I posted introduces this concept also.

Answer (score 1):

In the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20) you can find a very analytical description of the allowed background execution modes, under which circumstances you can use each one and also some best practices to follow. If your app follows nothing of the above, then things are getting fairly arbitrary. AFAIK there is no way to know when the operating system will kill your app or do anything to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking into the crash report with XCode Organizer. The crash report will have an exception code that shows why the application went away.

If you have a problem with the background operation, as hinted in the question and the answer from spassas, you will see the exception code 0xbad22222 in the crash report.

See [the Apple doc on exception codes](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-ANALYZING_CRASH_REPORTS-EXCEPTION_CODES) for more details.